# Extract multiple survfit() outputs into table

Tags: r, ggplot2, survminer

I have found a few pages on how to extract a single `survfit` to a table. However, I want to extract multiple summaries into a single `kable` (or other table format, if necessary). I combined multiple fits into a list for a `ggsurvplot_combine` and want to summarize them directly underneath in a single table in an R Markdown.

I created a reprex with the `lung` dataset that mimics what I have done for my analysis.

Code:

```
kmcombo_sex <- survfit(Surv(time, status) ~ sex, data = lung)
kmcombo_ph.ecog <- survfit(Surv(time, status) ~ ph.ecog, data = lung)
 
lung2 <- lung %>%
     mutate(kps_ord = case_when(
         ph.karno > 70 ~ 3,
         ph.karno > 50 ~ 2,
         TRUE ~ 1
     ))
 
kmcombo_kps <- survfit(Surv(time, status) ~ kps_ord, data = lung2)
 
kmlistexample <- list(kmcombo_sex, kmcombo_ph.ecog, kmcombo_kps)
kmlistexample
```

Output:

```
kmlistexample
[[1]]
Call: survfit(formula = Surv(time, status) ~ sex, data = lung)

        n events median 0.95LCL 0.95UCL
sex=1 138    112    270     212     310
sex=2  90     53    426     348     550

[[2]]
Call: survfit(formula = Surv(time, status) ~ ph.ecog, data = lung)

   1 observation deleted due to missingness 
            n events median 0.95LCL 0.95UCL
ph.ecog=0  63     37    394     348     574
ph.ecog=1 113     82    306     268     429
ph.ecog=2  50     44    199     156     288
ph.ecog=3   1      1    118      NA      NA

[[3]]
Call: survfit(formula = Surv(time, status) ~ kps_ord, data = lung2)

            n events median 0.95LCL 0.95UCL
kps_ord=1   7      6    122     105      NA
kps_ord=2  51     45    212     163     310
kps_ord=3 170    114    353     305     428
```

When I try the traditional way, I get a nested list of `survfit` objects:

```
kmlistexample_sum <- summary(kmlistexample)
kmlistexample_sum 
     Length Class   Mode
[1,] 17     survfit list
[2,] 18     survfit list
[3,] 17     survfit list
```

I also tried unlisting prior to using the `summary` function to no avail:

```
kmlistexample_sum <- summary(unlist(kmlistexample))
```

If all else fails, I can go back to each `survfit` object and extract what I need individually. I was hoping that there may be an easier way.

Comment: How about calling `tidy()` on each survfit object and then `bind_rows()` to combine the resulting tibbles?

Comment: Try `lapply(kmlistexample,summary)`.

Answer (score 1):

Found out that the `surv_median` function (part of `survminer` package) will summarize the median and 95%CI and can be stored in a new object. The code I utilized for my R Markdown is as follows:

```
require(knitr)

surv_median(kmlistexample) %>% 
  kable()
```

Result (did not adjust aesthetics at all):

```
|strata | median| lower| upper|
|:------|------:|-----:|-----:|
|sex=1  |    270|   212|   310|
|sex=2  |    426|   348|   550|

|strata    | median| lower| upper|
|:---------|------:|-----:|-----:|
|ph.ecog=0 |    394|   348|   574|
|ph.ecog=1 |    306|   268|   429|
|ph.ecog=2 |    199|   156|   288|
|ph.ecog=3 |    118|    NA|    NA|

|strata    | median| lower| upper|
|:---------|------:|-----:|-----:|
|kps_ord=1 |    122|   105|    NA|
|kps_ord=2 |    212|   163|   310|
|kps_ord=3 |    353|   305|   428|
```